# Scared budgie has a lot of problems

Tags: birds

My budgies (can't determine either of their ages) are both really concerning.

They are shy, and won't come near me despite me attempting for a *year* to get them to come near my hand.
They also won't eat any seeds. This concerns me because a budgie should be eating fresh fruits and vegetables, they won't come near any.

Is there anything I can do about these two problems? It's okay if you can only answer one.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour] to see how this site works, it only takes a minute. This is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, so we need you to clearly state one specific question you want answered or one problem you want us to help you solve. It could be anything from "Is this a health concern" to "I want to pet them" or anything in between. Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank your for the edit! But still your do not mention a clear aim to reach or use a questionmarl somewhere. You mention two aspects, food and fear. It is welcome to make two separate posts, one for each problem.

Comment: Of interest: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/31641/budgie-afraid-of-fingers

Comment: About eating: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26847/depressed-budgie/26892#26892